# MySQL Retrieving data from different tables and counting that data to different columns

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to retrieve some data from different tables in mysql but it get error for some reasons. I want to retrieve the total number of travelers who have traveled to brisbane and sydney.

Travelers (nickname, firstName, dob) == table 1
in table 1 there the nickname is a primary key.

TravelersBrisbane (travelID, datetime, travelLocation) == table 2 
in table 2 travelID is primary key.

Travelers_TravelersBrisbane (nickname, travelID) == table 3
in table 3 nickname and travelID are foreign keys,

TravelersSydney (nickname, travelID, datatime, travelLocation) == 4
in table 4 nickname, travelID, datetime are foreign keys.

Now I want to retrieve nickname for all travelers who have traveled one or more times to either of those cities as well as their the number of times they have travled to either of those two cities in seperate columns, the columns should totalTimesTraveledBris, TotalTimesTravelSyd.

I have used the below syntax but it wouldnt work and I get errors.

```
SELECT DISTINCT travelers.nickname,
count (Travelers_TravelersBrisbane.nickname) as totalTimesTraveledBris,
count (TravelersSydney.nickname) as TotalTimesTravelSyd
FROM TravelersSydney, travelers
inner join Travelers_TravelersBrisbane on TravelersSydney.nickname = 
Travelers_TravelersBrisbane.nickname
WHERE travelers.nickname IN (
SELECT nickname from TravelersSydney)
AND travelers.nickname IN (
SELECT nickname from Travelers_TravelersBrisbane);
```

That's my syntax for it but it doesn't work, Is anyone able to help ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is bad design to have separate tables for separate cities.  Instead, it would be better to have just a single travelers table with a column for the city.

Comment: At first, i see you are referencing table **travelers** but this table is not named on the clause FROM and neither on the JOINS

Comment: Hey @D. Smania I've updated it but it still wont work? Can you please have a look if I'm doing anything wrong. Cheers

Comment: Your result have to be only a number? I ask, because of this:  _I want to retrieve the total number of travelers who have traveled to brisbane and sydney_

Comment: yeah the result should be numbers for example if a traveler has traveled twice to both cities it should record 2. If it has traveled to both cities once it should be recorded as 1.